# WordPress: display Time but in the future

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm building a restaurant delivery website and would like to let the customers know the estimated arrival time.

For example, when the purchase is completed, I would like to tell them:

"Your order will arrive between (30 minutes from now) and (45 minutes from now)".

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: please share your existing code

Comment: Please share your code & explain in deep, so we get some idea about your problem. What you have tried? How do you calculate arrival time? Briefly explained context will be helpful to help you out.

Comment: i don't have code, i have no idea how to achieve this. There is no calculation to the arrival time. The estimate is default for everyone. 30 minutes to 45 minutes from now. So basically i want to display 'CURRENT TIME + 30 minutes" and "CURRENT TIME + 45 minutes". Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily in PHP using `strtotime("+45 minutes")`

```
$deliveryIn30 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." +30 minutes"));
$deliveryIn45 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." +45 minutes"));

echo "Your order will arrive between {$deliveryIn30} and {$deliveryIn45}.";
```

Edit: If you want to use the WordPress installation local time

```
$time = current_time( 'mysql' );
$deliveryIn30 = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($time) + 1800); // 30 mins * 60 secs = 1800
$deliveryIn45 = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($time) + 2700); // 45 mins * 60 secs = 2700

echo "Your order will arrive between {$deliveryIn30} and {$deliveryIn45}.";
```

Comment: this code is almost what I need! I see that it reads the UNIVERSAL TIME rather than the local time that I choose on my WordPress installation. Any idea how I can tell it to pick the local WordPress time instead?

Comment: hey dude, thanks so much, managed to resolve the TIMEZONE by adding `date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");` to the code! thanks

Comment: Ah ok no worries, I've updated my answer for the case of using the WordPress local time too :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to substract present datetime with delivery datetime
Like this

```
$datetime_now = new DateTime();
$delivery_dt = new DateTime('2020-08-08 20:20:00');
$count_down= $datetime_now->diff($delivery_dt);
echo $count_down->format('%h hours %i minutes');
```